# What's the major differences between Normalize CSS and Marx CSS?

Tags: css, normalize-css

I know what Normalize CSS does. But, recently I found Marx CSS. The features look quite similar to Normalize CSS. To be specific should we continue with Normalize CSS or is Marx CSS is a better option as it seems to be quite light-weighted or is it completely preference based?

http://matthewblode.com/marx/

https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: marx contains css that pre-styles elements, normalize is aimed at removing styling as much as possible while maintaining UX cross-browser. The equivalent of normalize would be `sanitize.css` used in the marx project.